# REACTJS tableBody.jsx component error : Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

Hard stuck after creating tableBody.jsx component and getting same error no matter how much changes i make.

This is moviesTable.jsx component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TableHeader from "./common/tableHeader";
import Like from "./common/like";
import TableBody from "./common/tableBody";

class MoviesTable extends Component {
  columns = [
    { path: "title", label: "Title" },
    { path: "genre", label: "Genre" },
    { path: "numberInStock", label: "Stock" },
    { path: "dailyRentalRate", label: "Rate" },
    {
      key: "like",
      content: (movie) => (
        <Like liked={movie.liked} onClick={() => this.props.onLike(movie)} />
      ),
    },
    {
      key: "delete",
      content: (movie) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(movie)}
          className="btn btn-danger"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      ),
    },
  ];
  render() {
    const { movies, onSort, sortColumn } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <table className="table">
          <TableHeader
            columns={this.columns}
            sortColumn={sortColumn}
            onSort={onSort}
          />
          <TableBody data={movies} columns={this.columns} />
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default MoviesTable;
```

And this is tableBody.jsx component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

class TableBody extends Component {
  renderCell = (item, column) => {
    if (column.content) return column.content(item);

    return _.get(item, column.path);
  };

  createKey = (item, column) => {
    return item._id + (column.path || column.key);
  };
  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.props;
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <tr key={item._id}>
            {columns.map((column) => (
              <td key={this.createKey(item, column)}>
                {this.renderCell(item, column)}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}

export default TableBody;
```

[https://anonfiles.com/ber1QcGcpd/Screenshot_65_png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHKS7.png)

this is the output i am getting by {console.log(this.renderCell(item, column))}.
I want to arrange the data given by renderCell function in a table like this...

[https://anonfiles.com/B8tdQ2G6pa/output_jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQSr.jpg)

while returning from tableBody.jsx component i'm getting this error : **(Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.)**

Comment: `this.renderCell(item, column)` unless that method returns a React node it is almost certainly the culprit.

Comment: @JaredSmith `<td key={this.createKey(item, column)}>{_.get(item, column.path);}</td>` 
giving the same error, even if i remove the renderCell function

Comment: That's...not how functions work. When I said "your problem is what that method returns" that means exactly that. Taking the return value and putting directly in place of the function call is *exactly the same thing*, so of course you're going to get the same error...you will have to change that into something React can render.

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: Don't know, you need to show what `_.get(item, column.path)` is returning, as well as tell us what you *expect* to see there.

Comment: @JaredSmith above is the link to the image files

Comment: Does `_.get(item, column.path).name` get you there?

Comment: @JaredSmith yes, but only one property is showing at a time

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a property from item in your `renderCell` function

```
renderCell = (item, column) => {
  if (column.content) return column.content(item);
  // Did you mean to use this in a react component??
  return _.get(item, column.path);
};
```

Ensure its not an object that is getting returned, and is a primitive data type.

Comment: no, renderCell function is not an issue, <td key={this.createKey(item, column)}>               {_.get(item, column.path);}</td> this is giving the same error

Comment: @DrDOMinance Kumar is correct, it doesn't matter whether you wrap it in a method or place it directly, whatever that is it's an object and not a valid React child.

Answer (score 0):

Path for the genre is not correct in the columns. Please change { path: "**genre**", label: "Genre" } to  { path: "**genre.name**", label: "Genre" } in the columns. Because of the incorrect path, the _.get() returns an object for genre with id and name instead of the name-value. Hence the error.