# unable to destructuring two objects simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, object, react-component

How can I map movies by using columns as a property reference.

Like

```
{movies.map(item => {columns.map(column => item.column.path)})}
```

but using this i'm getting result as `undefined`

Movies contains all details about movies

```
const movies = [
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z",
    liked: true,
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 8,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5,
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",
    title: "Trip to Italy",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5,
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181a",
    title: "Airplane",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5,
  }];
```

Columns contains all properties that are needed to access the movies

```
const columns = [
        { path: "title", label: "Title" },
        { path: "genre", label: "Genre" },
        { path: "numberInStock", label: "Stock" },
        { path: "dailyRentalRate", label: "Rate" }];
```

I know this problem can be solved using 2 loops.

1 outer loop for movies after getting each movie, use a 2nd internal loop to access the properties

*Update: After getting @rory-mccrossan answer*

Further, how can I map this data in a table such that

[image: Required data table]

This is the code part regarding the same that I used.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

class TableBody extends Component {
  renderCell = (item, column) => {
    if (column.content) return column.content(item);

    return _.get(item, column.path);
  };

  createKey = (item, column) => {
    return item._id + (column.path || column.key);
  };
  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.props;
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <tr key={item._id}>
            {columns.map((column) => (
              <td key={this.createKey(item, column)}>
                {this.renderCell(item, column)}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}

export default TableBody;
```

But I'm getting the **error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.)**

The main issue is that how can I map data in a table

Comment: _"but using this i'm getting result as `undefined`"_ - Because `{ ... }` creates a block and therefor "removes" the implicit `return` so the "inner" `.map()` call doesn't return anything -> `.map(item => columns.map(...))`

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues here. Firstly the braces around the second `map()` call will be interpreted as a code block, yet it does not return any value so the resulting array will be empty. Remove those braces.

Secondly, `item.column.path` needs to be `item[column.path]` as you're using `column.path` as the property accessor of `item`.

Here's a working example:

```js
const movies = [{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",title:"Terminator",genre:{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818",name:"Action"},numberInStock:6,dailyRentalRate:2.5,publishDate:"2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z",liked:!0},{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",title:"Die Hard",genre:{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818",name:"Action"},numberInStock:5,dailyRentalRate:2.5},{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",title:"Get Out",genre:{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820",name:"Thriller"},numberInStock:8,dailyRentalRate:3.5},{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",title:"Trip to Italy",genre:{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814",name:"Comedy"},numberInStock:7,dailyRentalRate:3.5},{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181a",title:"Airplane",genre:{_id:"5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814",name:"Comedy"},numberInStock:7,dailyRentalRate:3.5}];
const columns = [{path:"title",label:"Title"},{path:"genre",label:"Genre"},{path:"numberInStock",label:"Stock"},{path:"dailyRentalRate",label:"Rate"}];

let output = movies.map(item => columns.map(column => item[column.path]));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: that's working perfect, but my main intention of asking this question is to find the answer to this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106451/reactjs-tablebody-jsx-component-error-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Comment: Questions should be self contained. I'd suggest updating that question with more detail if the answers you're getting do not solve your issue.

Comment: No, that's not how this site works. You ask questions separately. You should not ask one question, get an answer that works and then edit the question to be something complely different.